# Laravel upload file to resource

Tags: file-upload, laravel

In Laravel I have a resource controller in which I need to handle picture uploads. In my create.blade.php I have the following form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'PhotoController@store', 'method' => 'post')); }}
{{Form::text('text'); }}
{{Form::file('photo');}}
{{Form::submit('Submit');}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

In my PhotoController I have the following store function

```
public function store()
{
    if (Input::hasFile('photo'))
    {
         return 'Got the photo';
    }
    else { return Input::get('text'); }
}
```

The input from the field 'text' is returned, however it does not seem like Laravel can find the photo I upload.
I tried to change the method to put and create a custom function to handle this but with the same result. How come I cannot make Laravel recognize that I've attached a file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `'files' => true` and `'enctype' =>"multipart/form-data"` to your form like so

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'PhotoController@store', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true, 'enctype' =>"multipart/form-data")); }}
```

In regard to the `POST` and `PUT` options it depends on what you are doing. As you are using the `store` resource method, you should use `POST`. If you are going to use the `update` method then you would use `PUT`.

For resource controllers the methods and HTTP requests work like this

```
 +-------------------+-------------+
 | Controller method | HTTP Method |
 +-------------------+-------------+
 | index             | GET         |
 | create            | GET         |
 | store             | POST        |
 | show              | GET         |
 | edit              | GET         |
 | update            | PUT / PATCH |
 | destroy           | DELETE      |
 +-------------------+-------------+
```

The confusing ones are `create` and `edit` which you may think should be `POST` but remember this are the pages that 'get' the forms in order to edit or create an item.

Once you have your file you will need to do something with it. Therefore, next you are going to want to do something with the file, so you will need

```
$photo = Input::file('photo');
$photo->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

Documentation on these and all the other `Input::file()` methods can be found in the [Laravel documentation here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files).

Comment: Works like a charm. Haven't tested the move function yet - but it now registers that I've uploaded a file and returns "Got the photo" when I make an attachment.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'images.store', 'role' => 'form', 'files' => true)) }}
```

This is what I use for my file upload form, I don't have `'enctype'` or `'method'` and I point to a route instead of an action.

This is what it translates to in HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="action url" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="token value">
```

As you can see the `'enctype'` and `'method'` is added by the `Form::open` helper function. The `role="form"` is for [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) to format the form correctly.

About HTML and forms: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html

Comment: Works very fine aswell. What would be the advantage of this solution compared to  DavidT's which also works well?

Comment: No advantage really, just pointed out that a couple of the parameters  were optional and used a route instead of an action. This isn't a "another solution", we are both pointing out the same. His answer is excellent :)